# How to change defaults of media when importing audio in moodle?

Tags: php, html, html5-audio, moodle

How can I disable the audio controls by default in moodle? So that I need not to uncheck this checkbox every time I add media using default moodle tools?

--
I simply want to add audio, with "audio controls" unchecked by default.

EXPLANATION:

[image: CLICK HERE TO SEE SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have done so far. Maybe you want some hints on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have moodle installed to my website, and created course and quiz. My question and explanation of what I need is clear "I simply want to add audio (audio player), with "audio controls" unchecked by default." I will make now some screenshots to make it even easier to understand...

Comment: P.S., all advices and suggestions are welcome. Thanks to all in stackoverflow. Especially thanks to those who comments under this question ;)